# Why on smaller screens, does my nested-menu not work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, nested-lists

On smaller screens, I want the dropdown menu and nested menu to only appear when they're clicked. I.e you click apple, and red apple and green apple appear, if you click red apple, tasty appears. Etc. However, I can't seem to get the click to work after the initial clicking of apple shows red apple and green apple. I can never get tasty to appear on smaller screens.

https://codepen.io/Dezalops/pen/yLGMbqQ
Here's the codepen

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <style>
      /* Basic Styles */
      .navbar {
        background-color: #333;
      }

      .main-menu {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
      }

      .menu-item {
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 20px;
      }

      a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 10px;
        display: block;
      }

      /* Dropdown Styles */
      .submenu {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #444;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        padding: 0;
        z-index: 1;
      }

      /* Media Query for Larger Screens (Hover) */
      @media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
        .menu-item:hover .submenu {
          display: block;
        }

        .submenu li:hover .nested-menu {
          display: block;
        }
      }

      /* Nested Menu Styles */
      .submenu li {
        padding: 10px;
      }

      .nested-menu {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 100%;
        background-color: #555;
        padding: 0;
        z-index: 2;
      }
    </style>
    <title>Navbar</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <ul class="main-menu">
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a href="#">Apple</a>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li class="menu-item">
              <a href="#">Red Apple</a>
              <ul class="nested-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Tasty</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item">
              <a href="#">Green Apple</a>
              <ul class="nested-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Sweet</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a href="#">Cake</a>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li class="menu-item">
              <a href="#">Chocolate Cake</a>
              <ul class="nested-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Rich</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item">
              <a href="#">Vanilla Cake</a>
              <ul class="nested-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Light</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a href="#">Tea</a>
          <ul class="submenu">
            <li class="menu-item">
              <a href="#">Black Tea</a>
              <ul class="nested-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Strong</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-item">
              <a href="#">Green Tea</a>
              <ul class="nested-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Healthy</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <script>
      // JavaScript for toggling the dropdowns on click for smaller screens
      const menuItems = document.querySelectorAll(".menu-item");

      menuItems.forEach((menuItem) => {
        menuItem.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
          if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
            // Prevent event bubbling
            event.stopPropagation();

            // Toggle the active class to show/hide the submenu
            menuItem.classList.toggle("active");

            // Toggle the submenu visibility
            const submenu = menuItem.querySelector(".submenu");
            if (submenu) {
              submenu.style.display =
                submenu.style.display === "block" ? "none" : "block";
            }
          }
        });
      });

      // Close submenus when clicking anywhere outside for smaller screens
      document.addEventListener("click", () => {
        if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
          menuItems.forEach((menuItem) => {
            menuItem.classList.remove("active");
            const submenu = menuItem.querySelector(".submenu");
            if (submenu) {
              submenu.style.display = "none";
            }
          });
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried numerous javascript and css styles and nothing works, ever.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your event click function will only target the "submenu" class to change the display and your nested menus only have the class "nested-menu" so when you click on "chocolate cake" the submenu item returned is null. If you add the submenu class to each nested menu element it will "work" but will still have some issues. (it will break your css hover effect, and nested menus will stay open)

I think your best solution involves setting up a different click event on the submenus that is intended to target your nested menus.